# Pass message to jsp (struts2)

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I need to do the following:
Once user clicks on the button, it should trigger an action, once action is completed it should send the proper message to the jsp page to be shown to user, I am using the following code but do not have any idea how to complete it.

```
   <sj:a id="Submit" href="%{ajaxText}" targets="div1">Add</sj:a>
   <s:url id="ajaxText" value="/myAction.action"/>
```

Comment: what is not working? and i believe you can go with simple Jquery which is more flexible than using the plugin if you are not using any fancy widgets of plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy:

JSP:

```
<s:url id="ajaxText" value="/myAction.action"/>
<sj:a id="Submit" href="%{ajaxText}" targets="div1">Add</sj:a>
<s:actionmessage />
```

Action class:

```
public String execute() throws Exception {
    addActionMessage("your message");
    return Action.SUCCESS;
}
```

Configuration:

```
<action name="myAction" class="">
    <result name="success">path/to/your.jsp</result>
</action>
```

the message sould be shown.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the code caused following error  <<No tag "ActionMessage" defined in tag library imported with prefix "s">>

Comment: @EmeEmertana Then you're doing something wrong, like using `<s:ActionMessage>` instead of `<s:actionmessage>`. [Here are the tag docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/actionmessage.html); I'm reasonably sure the tag exists.